# Default value parameter in Groovy as middle argument

Tags: function, groovy, parameters, default-value

I have a simple question. Why I can ommit middle parameter in case below?

```
    def testMethod(arg1, arg2 = "arg2", arg3) {
    println arg1
    println arg2
    println arg3
}

def "testMethod"() {
    given:
    testMethod("arg1", "arg3")
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In the method definition, you basically hardcode the second parameter, so it has a value when you call the method.

Comment: @ou_ryperd Correct me if I am wrong. Is it necessary (somethinf like minimum requirement) to supply all parameters without default value if I want to call `testMethod`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In groovy you can assign default values to method's arguments, making those arguments optional.

Usually the optional arguments are the trailing ones, and that makes sence from the POV of calling such methods.

You could also declare default values for the middle arguments, like you did. In this case you should be aware of which arguments will get the defaults and which will not.

Consider the extension of your example:

```
def testMethod(arg1, arg2 = "arg2", arg3) {
    println arg1
    println arg2
    println arg3
}
testMethod 1, 3

println '-----------'

def testMethod1(arg1, arg2 = "arg2", arg3 = 'arg3') {
    println arg1
    println arg2
    println arg3
}
testMethod1 1,2
```

It prints:

```
1
arg2
3
-----------
1
2
arg3
```

So, when calling both methods with 2 arguments, the `testMethod` replaces the 2nd arg with default, whereas the `testMethod1` defaults the 3rd arg.